# Issue with pywebhdfs module

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to use pywebhdfs module in Python to interact with Hortonworks Hadoop sandbox. I tried the following three commands:

```
from pywebhdfs.webhdfs import PyWebHdfsClient
hdfs = PyWebHdfsClient(user_name="root",port=50070,host="localhost")
hdfs.make_dir('/newDirectory')
```

I get the following error on running the last command:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10035, 'A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately'))
```

The sandbox is running and I am able to create directories directly on it using Putty. However, it doesn't work through Python.

Can someone help with this error?

Answer (score 0):

I believe 'root' cannot create directory on the '/' node of HDFS, since 'root' user is not a HDFS superuser unless, of course, you changed it.

Could you confirm if you can create '/newDirectory' using root user or perhaps create the directory where root has permissions or choose another user?